# Calculate an optimization function

Tags: functions, optimization, linear-programming

I have three variables $B, E$ and $F$. Those values taking values between $B, E, F \in [0, 1]$. Moreover, there is also the following constraint: $B + E + F = 1$. I want to find a function $f = aB + bE + cF$, so to calculate those $a, b, c$ so as the following conditions to be met:

$f \rightarrow 0$, when $B  \rightarrow 1$

$f \rightarrow 1$, when $E  \rightarrow 1$

$f \rightarrow 2$, when $F  \rightarrow 1$

Where with symbol $\rightarrow$ I meant the limit (the $f$ to be close to those values). Moreover, I want my function to be continuous and the values not to change drastically. Is there a chance that those conditions could be met from my function? Is there a chance that I can do so with non-linear functions?

Comment: What should happen when $B \to 1$ and $E \to 1$ at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the assumptions correctly, $a=0$, $b=1$, $c=2$.

Comment: if $f = E+2F$ then as $F \to 1$, you have $f \to E+2 \ne 2$

Comment: I want when $B$ is close to 1 $f$ to be close to 0, when $E$ is close to 1 $f$ to be close to 1 and when $F$ is close to 1 $f$ to be close to 2. Also I want the function $f$ to be continuous function.

Comment: But $B+E+F=1$ so as $F \to 1$, $E \to 0$ so it would work. Unless I am missing something obvious?

Comment: It is working but I want also some gradually decrease to 0 using the B